# How to plot a "x and y" inequality function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I'd like to plot the following function :

$$(\frac{d}{2}+1)\big\lceil\sqrt{8x+1}\big\rceil \leq 2x(\big\lceil\sqrt{4d+1}\big\rceil-1)+1$$

It's ok to plot without the ceiling function I suppose.
So far, this has been unsuccessful on Symbolab, Cymath, Quickmath and Photomath.
I've tried WolframAlpha, which seems to work fine, but it only allows a small part of the plot (unless I pay).
I'm installing MatLab at the moment, but meanwhile, does anyone perhaps know of a way to plot my function?

Comment: Are you looking for software recommendations, or do you want to solve it by hand?

Comment: I'd like to solve for x. I'd also like to plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator using $y$ not $d$ and it should work (did for me at least).

The syntax is pretty straightforwards (similar to LaTeX): `ceil` gives you the ceiling function, `<=` turns into $\leq$, `sqrt` turns into $\sqrt{\hphantom{xx}}$ etc.
[image]

Comment: do you happen to know if it's possible to define the domain of the function? I'd want the function to only consider natural numbers, i.e., N -> N

Comment: Click on the spanner in the top right, there you can define the domain/range